# Compute $P(X_{(1)} + X_{(3)} \le 1),$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Any Idea why I keep getting $3/4$ ?

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3},$ be independent, $U(0, 1)$-distributed random variables and $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, X_{(3)}$ be the corresponding order variables.

Compute (a) : $P(X_{(1)} + X_{(3)} \le 1),$
I can't seem to get the book answewr which is 0.5.

---

I'm proceeding as the following:

I set: $$U=X_{(1)} + X_{(3)}, V=X_{(1)}$$
$f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X_{(1)}X_{(3)}}(x_1,x_{3})=\int_0^{x_3}6d_{x_2}.|J|$ with J=1

I get that $f_U(u)=\int_0^{u/2}6(u-v)dv$

after the calculation I get that $f_{U}(u)=\frac{9}{4}u^2$
and $F_U(1)=3/4$ 
which is different from the 1/2 in the book.

**Update:**
*I think I got an error when looking for the range of $x_2$.
It is known that: $0<x_1<x_2<x_3<1$
When  integrating with respect to $x_2$, I get confused as to why in this case we take $x_1<x_2<x_3$ as opposed to some case where we jump some variables*

---

As for example with the same setting as above and one more varible and order statistic, for the range $0<x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4<1$ when looking for $f_{x_{(3)},x_{(4)}}(x_3,x_4)$ $$f_{x_{(3)},x_{(4)}}(x_3,x_4)=\int_0^{x_3} \int_0^{x_2}  f_{x_{(1)},x_{(2)},x_{(3)},x_{(4)}}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) dx_1dx_2$$ instead of 
 $$f_{x_{(3)},x_{(4)}}(x_3,x_4)= \int_{x_2}^{x_3} \int_0^{x_2} f_{x_{(1)},x_{(2)},x_{(3)},x_{(4)}}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) dx_1dx_2$$

Comment: Are you sure that the $X_{(i)}$ are independent? If so then what is the role of $X_{(2)}$ in this all? Normally the notation $X_{(i)}$ is used for ordered random variables.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I miswrote that part. As a side question, if the order statistics are all independent then can I just treat them as variables and then compute $F_W(1)$ for a CDF such that W~U(0,2). Excuse any ridicule question I may have.

Comment: @MahamadA.Kanouté Order statistics are never independent; note the dependency $X_{(1)}<X_{(2)}<X_{(3)}$. For solving the problem, you could work with the joint pdf of $(X_{(1)},X_{(3)})$.

Comment: Thank you, Side question closed. Do you have any idea why the answer to the question instead of 3/4 is 1/2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order variables are not at all independent, for example $P(X_{(1)} > X_{(2)})=0$ and similar relations between the other order variables.

To get you started, let's find the joint distribution of $X_{(1)},X_{(3)}$, that means

$$p(x_1,x_3) = P(X_{(1)} < x_1 \land X_{(3)} < x_3),$$

where we restrict $x_1,x_3$ to the interval $[0,1]$ and $(x_1 \le x_3)$.

The trick is to express this as $p(x_1,x_3) = P(X_{(3)} < x_3)-P(X_{(1)} \ge x_1 \land X_{(3)} < x_3) $ and both terms on the right hand side are relatively easy to evaluate!

$X_{(3)} < x_3$ is **equivalent** to $(X_1 < x_3 \land X_2 < x_3 \land X_3 < x_3)$, just remember that $X_{(3)}$ is the maximum of $X_1,X_2$ and $X_3$.

Since the 3 conditions concern different and independent variables, we get

$$P(X_{(3)} < x_3) = P(X_1 < x_3 \land X_2 < x_3 \land X_3 < x_3)=P(X_1 < x_3)P(X_2 < x_3)P(X_3 < x_3) = x_3^3.$$

With the same argument, just applied to the minimum, we get $X_{(1)} \ge x_1$ is equivalent to $(X_1 \ge x_1 \land X_2 \ge x_1 \land X_3 \ge x_1)$ so we get

$$\begin{array}{}
(X_{(1)} \ge x_1 \land X_{(3)} < x_3) & = & (X_1 \ge x_1 \land X_2 \ge x_1 \land X_3 \ge x_1) \land (X_1 < x_3 \land X_2 < x_3 \land X_3 < x_3) \\
& = & (X_1 \ge x_1 \land X_1 < x_3) \land \\
&   & (X_2 \ge x_1 \land X_2 < x_3) \land \\
&   & (X_3 \ge x_1 \land X_3 < x_3),  \\
\end{array}
$$
by using the fact that $\land$ is commutative and associative. Each line in the last equation deals with one variable, the variable in each line is independent of other lines, so we can again use the product rule to find it's probability:

$$P(X_{(1)} \ge x_1 \land X_{(3)} < x_3) = \\P(X_1 \ge x_1 \land X_1 < x_3)P(X_2 \ge x_1 \land X_2 < x_3)P(X_3 \ge x_1 \land X_3 < x_3)=(x_3-x_1)^3.$$

Combining the 2 results, we finally get the joined probability:

$$p(x_1,x_3)=x_3^3 - (x_3-x_1)^3=x_1^3-3x_1^2x_3+3x_1x_3^2$$

The remainder is standard technique: The density of the joint distribution of $X_{(1)},X_{(3)}$ is

$${\partial p(x_1,x_3) \over \partial x_1 \partial x_3} = 6(x_3-x_1)$$

and then you have to calculate the double integrel

$$\int_0^{1\over 2}\int_{x_1}^{1-x_1} 6(x_3-x_1)dx_3dx_1.$$

Note that the lower boundary of the $x_3$ integral is $x_1$, as there is no mass in the distribution at a point where the maximum of 3 values is greater than the minimum of those 3 values. That's also why the $x_1$ integral stops at $1 \over 2$: If the minimum gets over $1 \over 2$, the sum of minimum and maximum must be greater than $1$.

Doing the integrals is not complicated and the final result is actually $1 \over 2$.

I assume there is some symmetry argument that gives the result more easily, but I couldn't find a convincing one.

Comment: Although I understand everything you wrote I don't see why you didn't choose to use a dummy variable with the Jacobian technic and then take the marginal of what is needed.

Comment: I have some questions:                                                                                             
Do you have a name for the technic you used here?                                          
Why a double integral over the joint ? is it like looking for the $F(x)=\int_{\infty}^xf(s)ds ?$ .Also, If I get what you're implying, I can always get a joint and then figure the restrictions applied by the problem like in this case $X_{(1)} + X_{(3)} \le 1 $ and then integrate the whole pdf over the restrictions to get the value asked for ?

Comment: I don't know about marginals and the Jacobian technic, sorry! If you can write an answer using that (maybe pointing to parts of my answer for things that are the same so you don't need to cover them again), that might show an approach to the problem, never a bad thing! For the second question: Yes, the basic idea is that the joint distribution covers everything there is know about those 2 variables, then you can go in an apply the restriction. If may be easier/possible to get a distribution for $X_{(1)}+X_{(3)}$ by itself, as indicated in the answer by zhoraster.

Answer (score 5):

Since the distribution $U(0,1)$ is symmetric around $1/2$, we have  $(X_{(1)},X_{(2)},X_{(3)}) \overset{d}= (1-X_{(3)},1-X_{(2)},1-X_{(1)})$, whence 
$$
\mathrm P (X_{(1)} + X_{(3)} \le 1) = \mathrm P (1-X_{(3)} + 1- X_{(1)} \le 1) = \mathrm P (X_{(1)} + X_{(3)} \ge 1),
$$
so, in view of continuity,
$$
\mathrm P (X_{(1)} + X_{(3)} \le 1) = \frac12.
$$

Comment: this is the easiest way to visualize this particular problem, will it work for n variables  ?

Comment: I feel like no matter the number of variable it will get 1/2

Comment: @MahamadA.Kanouté, if you're speaking of $X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}$, then yes of course, the same argument works.